# How to check if a dynamic object is an array in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `dynamic` object that sometimes is an `object` and sometimes is an `object[]`.

How can I check if the dynamic object is an array?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [`Type.IsArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isarray%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

From MSDN:

```
int [] array = {1,2,3,4};
Type t = array.GetType();
// t.IsArray == true
Console.WriteLine("The type is {0}. Is this type an array? {1}", t, t.IsArray);
```

Comment: you'r right, I thought it would not work just because it is dynamic(GetType is not shown on intellisense, of course...), but after compile it works fine. thanks

Answer (score 7):

Why not just 'is' operator (I just did quick test on immediate windows of Visual Studio debugger), and it works. but not sure if Tim's answer is optimal.

```
void foo(object o)
{
if( o is System.Array)
{
//its array
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement Rango's original response, a more generic way to determine is to use the type's **IsSerializable** property. Because if the object is a List or any other collection, the IsArray returns false.

```
int [] array = {1,2,3,4};
Type t1 = array.GetType();
// t1.IsArray == true
List<int> list = new List();
list.AddRange(array);
Type t2 = list.GetType();
//t2.IsArray = false;
//t2.IsSerializable = true;

foreach(var i in list) {
        // do stuff
}
```

Comment: `"some text".GetType().IsSerializable` is also true but is not an array or list